# 2560x1440 resolution with DVI-D

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I want to connect an Eizo monitor to a Windows 7 computer. It is connected through a DVI-D single link cable, plugged into the single link DVI-D port. When setting the screen resolution to 2560x1440, the screen gets all blurry and unreadable. How can I solve this? Do I need to plug the cable into the dual link port?

Comment: Yes. See gronostaj's answer. He did not write a yes, but I'm sure you understand he meant that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Wikipedia article on [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface):

> In single-link mode, the maximum pixel clock frequency is 165 MHz that supports a maximum resolution of 2.75 megapixels (including blanking interval) at 60 Hz refresh. For practical purposes, this allows a maximum 16:10 screen resolution of 1920×1200 at 60 Hz.
>
> To support higher-resolution display devices, the DVI specification contains a provision for dual link. Dual-link DVI doubles the number of TMDS pairs, effectively doubling the video bandwidth. As a result, higher resolutions up to 2560 × 1600 are supported at 60 Hz.